# How to filter datetime.Month from mongo collection by aggregation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-web-api

I have a *Mongo collection* that contains a dateTime field called **"DateOfCreation"**. Given that I have a specific number of month, how can I get all documents that matches to month of the **DateOfCreation** field?

*Below, is what I tried to do, but it does not work and returns 0 Documents.*

```
var documents = Collection.Aggregate()
     .Match(new BsonDocument("DateOfCreation", new BsonDocument("$month", new BsonDocument("$eq", 3))))
     .Group(groupFields)
     .ToList();
```

**3** - is my number of month (march)

Similarly, I would like to do it for **year**, **day** and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how to translate this to C#, what you need is `$month` inside of `$expr`, with `$eq`, like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match:{$expr:{$eq:[{$month:"$DateOfCreation"},3]}}}])
```

Comment: something like [this](https://gist.github.com/dj-nitehawk/bad7ea6fb9bf39d88e14f089236b2fb5) can be done in c#